# Twilio en queued calls not coming through to agent phone

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-taskrouter

I am using Twilio Studio to configure an IVR system and was successfully able to do that. Now I am trying to create a queue with few agents so that the calls are not missed. I was able to create a Task Router and create a queue under that, as follows.
[image: Task Router]
I have added two agents to the queue as follows
[image: WOrker]
Now when I make a call, I can hear the music, but the calls are not coming through to the phone. Not sure what I have to do now

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The task workflow goes something a little like this:

> Call comes into queue -> Task created -> Task is pending -> Workflow finds Worker -> Reservation created -> Reservation accepted -> Call is routed to worker

From what I can tell, you've done everything but accept the reservation for your worker.

To do that you need to set the *Assignment Callback URL* for your Workflow. Then, when the reservation is created for a worker Twilio will send a webhook (HTTP request) to that URL. Your application can then accept the reservation and dequeue it immediately, or do a bunch of other things. I recommend you read through the documentation on [Task Lifecycle: workflows and assignment](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/lifecycle-task-workflows-and-assignment) for an overview followed by how to [Handle Assignment Callbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/handle-assignment-callbacks) for how to put that into action and produce your assignment callback handler.

The simplest thing you can respond with is the `dequeue` instruction which will connect the call to your worker's contact_uri. That would look like this:

```
{ "instruction": "dequeue" }
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I am not trying to use a webhook here. I want to use this with the IVR that I  have created using Twilio studio. Is there any documentations for that

Comment: You can enqueue a call from Studio, but from there taskrouter is going to take over, as I’ve described. And you need to respond to a webhook. It’s all in the links to the docs I shared in my answer.

Comment: I don't want to use a webhook. Why would I need a webhook if I am trying to create a simple IVR

Comment: is there any option in the studio, where I can forward my call to a number, if that number is unavailable or do not pick, forward to another number, with all these having a call record option.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is not an option in Studio where you can forward a call to a number and then if that's not answered forward it to another. This is why I suggested TaskRouter and using the dequeue instruction as above.

Comment: I see that you have twimlet which could be used for this purpose. Do you have the option to connect twilio studio with twimlet?

Comment: I was thinking of using the MAKE HTTP REQUEST widget and use the URL of a Twimlet  in the widget and use that Twilmet to do what I want

Comment: I've not tried it with a Twimlet, but that might just work. The call will leave the studio flow and will be controlled by the TwiML from the Twimlet, but that should be fine for your use case.